# Function that return a generic type not work without a concrete type

Tags: typescript

I expect this code works but is not:

```
interface Foo {
  foo(): boolean;
}

interface GenericFoo<T = {}> {
  bar(): T
}

function testFoo<T extends Foo>()
 : GenericFoo<T> {
// : GenericFoo<Foo> {
  return {
    bar() {
     return {
       foo() { return true },
     }
    },
  }
}
```

Setting return of testFoo to:

```
GenericFoo<Foo> // Typecheck OK
```

Not work

```
GenericFoo<T> // Typecheck FAIL
```

What will be the correct way to do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because `T` extends `Foo` does not mean the object literal `{ foo() { return true } }` 
will be compatible with `T`.

What if `T` is defined as `{ foo(): boolean, goo(): string }` at call site. This call is valid, as the type extends `Foo` but the function does not supply the `bar` method as the caller would expect

The only way to get the compiler to stop complaining is to use a type assertion, although as highlighted above this is not type safe:

```
interface Foo {
    foo(): boolean;
}

interface GenericFoo<T = {}> {
    bar(): T
}

function testFoo<T extends Foo>()
    : GenericFoo<T> {
    return {
        bar() {
            return {
                foo() { return true },
            } as T
        },
    }
}

testFoo<Foo>().bar().foo() //ok
testFoo<{ foo(): boolean; goo(): string }>().bar().goo() // runtime error
```